# Change Color of STATIC table view header does not work

Tags: uitableview, colors, tableview, cell, uicolor

Hi guys I have a small problem.
I created a table view with static cells in storyboard. Now I will change the color of my section headers, but I don´t know why this isn´t working. For normal table views I use this code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = UIView()
    footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return footer
}
```

I wrote that in my UITableViewController File which is linked to my Tableview Controller in storyboard, but the headers stay in that grey color. When I use the same code without static cells the header´s color changes to red.

I hope you can help me.

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use viewForHeaderInSection to change 'header' properties instead of viewForFooterInSection.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this was the biggest and dumbest mistake i ever made. The mistake was so obvious. I worked on that problem for 3 days now. Thank you! (And sorry for wasting your time with such a dumb question). Have a nice day.